# Python script to post api

Tags: python-2.7, rest

I'm using the following script to post API to my application

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import getopt
import smtplib
import requests
import json

payload = {
"eventType": "xxxx-cnsn-32324-333-22323",
"shortDesc" : "Sample Event",
"systemIdentity" : {
"ip" : "127.0.0.1"
},
"user" : "test user",
"properties" : {
  "DeviceName":"DeviceName",
  "AlertType":"NodeDown",
  "occurrenceTime":"1033432123432"
  }

r = requests.post('http://www.testapi.com/api/v3/events', payload)
print(r.url)
```

I'm getting the following error

```
File "./test.py", line 22
r = requests.post('http://www.testapi.com/api/v3/events', payload)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Missing a `}` on line 21 to close the payload datastructure.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you forgot to add the `data` keyword

```
r = requests.post('http://www.testapi.com/api/v3/events', data = payload)
```

And the braces of the payload dict are wrong.

```
payload = {
"eventType": "xxxx-cnsn-32324-333-22323",
"shortDesc" : "Sample Event",
"systemIdentity" : {
"ip" : "127.0.0.1"
},
"user" : "test user",
"properties" : {
  "DeviceName":"DeviceName",
  "AlertType":"NodeDown",
  "occurrenceTime":"1033432123432"
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it working now as expected. Changed the data to json as well since the server takes input in a jason format.